# Does setInterval() make the animation start on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code for a carousel but its not working as I supposed it should.

```
                            var totalItems = $('.inner li').length,
                        currentItem = 1,
                        $inner = $('.inner li'),
                        width = $inner.outerWidth(true);

                        setInterval(function() {
                            $inner.animate({
                                right: '+=' + width
                            }, 500);
                            currentItem += 1;
                        }, 500);
```

You can view the example at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zwm5p/)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
This is the entire code I have working for another carousel.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

        var totalItems = $('.inner li').length,
            currentItem = 1,
            $inner = $('.inner li'),
            width = $inner.outerWidth(true),
            speed = 400,
            delay = 4000;

        var timer = setInterval(function() {
            if (currentItem === totalItems) {
                $inner.animate({
                    right: '-=' + width * (totalItems-1) + 'px'
                }, speed);
                currentItem = 1;
            } else {
                $inner.animate({
                    right: '+=' + width
                }, speed);
                currentItem += 1;
            }
        }, delay);

        $('.carousel').hover (function(ev) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }, function(ev){
            timer = setInterval(function() {
                if (currentItem === totalItems) {
                    $inner.animate({
                        right: '-=' + width * (totalItems-1) + 'px'
                    }, speed);
                    currentItem = 1;
                } else {
                    $inner.animate({
                        right: '+=' + width
                    }, speed);
                    currentItem += 1;
                }
        }, delay);
        });
        $('#right').click(function () {
            if (currentItem === totalItems) {
                $inner.animate({
                    right: '-=' + width * (totalItems-1) + 'px'
                }, speed);
                currentItem = 1;
            } else {
                $inner.animate({
                    right: '+=' + width,
                }, speed);
                currentItem += 1;
            }
        });
        $('#left').click(function () {
            if (currentItem === 1) {
                $inner.animate({
                    right: '+=' + width * (totalItems-1) + 'px'
                }, speed);
                currentItem = totalItems;
            } else {
                $inner.animate({
                    right: '-=' + width
                }, speed);
                currentItem -= 1;
            }
        });
```

});

Comment: The interval is working, what doesn't work is your markup and your logic

Comment: *"I supposed it should"* ... and how it should work? At every 500ms animate by the whole `UL` width?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan My code is targeting the `li` width isn't it?

Comment: See my updated answer - try setting position: absolute on .inner li and you will see movement. This is just to show you the general direction, as your layout will not be what you wanted with position: absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

It just set's up an interval at which the passed function is called, so if you pass 500ms as an interval, the function will be called (about) 500ms from now, then (about) 1 second from now, then ...

setInterval also has nothing to do with page load, if that is what you meant (e.g. it doesn't depend on body load or anything like that, but the moment it gets executed)

I'm saying *about* because browser timing isn't very exact (for several reasons). Also, you should save the returned value of setInterval in a variable, and make sure to clean up the interval when you don't need it anymore. Depending on browser, this is normally done automatically on page unload, but on some older browsers it might not happen until the browser is closed.

Edit: Looking at the fiddle, your problem is with css, not with javascript. Your `li` need to be positioned `relative` or `absolute`, otherwise setting `right` property will have no effect. You could also set `margin-right`/`margin-left`.

Comment: I updated my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwm5p/2/) to the code I have for a working carousel, but when I add to this page it does not work.

Comment: @AndresRivera Updated answer. Your problem is with css, not js.

Comment: I was looking at my css too. The `overflow:hidden;` is not working for my `.carousel` class. Should I add a Wrapper around my carousel?

Comment: @AndresRivera position:absolute and overflow:hidden don't play well together, but if you use margin-right/-left or position:relative it should work with overflow being invisible.

Comment: Thank you @griffin, I was also wondering why is my question getting negative votes? Just wondering.

Comment: @AndresRivera Probably because your question (the subject) isn't what you want to ask/has nothing to do with the answer. Your implied question is "why isn't this jQuery animation working", but you're asking "Does setInterval ...". Also the "it should" part is very vague - you don't state what you think it _should_ do (people don't like to need to go into JS Fiddles to find out what the question is about). I can only guess, as I didn't downvote.

Comment: Oh ok I need to learn how to ask questions properly. I'm kinda new at this.